How to remove this towel ring?
how can I remove this ring towel ring? I am not sure what kind of screw it is. Help is appreciated, thank you!


rotate till you see a hex screw

there's a black hole stick something in there and feel around

IDK why the hole would be rectangular for a round set screw.  My guess would be you stick a small flathead screwdriver in there and either pry or push some kind of spring clip.

there is often a small "set screw" holding these covers on. you have to kind of hunt for them thru that hole, they tend to be pointing to the bottom (6 oclock) or to one side or the other (3 or 9 oclock) they are usually turned with small allen keys you can see what they look like , here is a image of a set you can find for sale online 
